# Rails console - use image_tag method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, irb, actionview, actionviewhelper

How can I execute a image_tag method in a Rails console

1. Run the console
   $ rails c
2. Load helpers

   > include ActionView::Helpers
3. Execute the command

   > image_tag('test.png')

I got a strange error.
[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK... I found the solution. The error is showing only in Rails 3 but I fixed it by setting the

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://..."
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://..."
```

in my environemnt file (e.g. development.rb).
Unbelievable!

This functionality is now part of a plugin https://github.com/xpepermint/js_erb.

Answer (score 23):

Not sure why you're getting that error. It is strange.

But the Rails Console exposes the helper methods through the helper variable. So this should work:

```
helper.image_tag('test.png')
```